# Converting png logo to white

Tags: logo, png

I have a logo that is in a png format (black lettering, transparent background). I want to convert this to a white logo lettering with a transparent background. How can I do this in Lightroom or Photoshop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Image > Adjustments > Invert`

Answer (score 1):

Invert it.

[image]

Cmd/i [Mac] Presumably Ctrl/i [Win]

From

[image]

to

[image]